# Kommentarbausteine auf Deutsch oder Englisch?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Mir ist gerade aufgefallen, dass automatisch eingefügte Kommentare in Englisch gehalten zu sein scheinen. In [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/76041/cmu-f%c3%bcr-die-deutsche-sprache-gesucht-deutsche-w%c3%b6rterliste-mit-silbentrennung), die auf Deutsch gestellt wurde, hatte ich ein Duplikat vorgeschlagen. Darauf hin erschien in den Kommentaren automatisch ein "Does this answer your question?", dass angesichts der übrigen Konversation ziemlich aus der Reihe fällt. Darüber hinaus hat es den Fragesteller völlig unnötigerweise dazu gebracht, auf Englisch zu reagieren.

Ist das so sinnvoll? Wäre es möglich, solche Bausteine (auch?) auf Deutsch anzubieten?

Die grundsätzliche *Möglichkeit* einer vollständigen Lokalisiserung, also die Übersetzung **aller** verwendeten Textelemente, existiert: pt.stackoverflow.com, ru.stackoverflow.com und ja.stackoverflow.com sind Beispiele dafür. Aber auch bei den auf Sprache orientierten Seiten gibt es ein Beispiel: Neben der nicht-lokalisierten Seite russian.steckexchange.com gibt es auch [rus.stackexchange.com](https://rus.stackexchange.com), "для лингвистов и энтузиастов русского языка", *für Linguisten und Enthusiasten der russischen Sprache*.

Answer (score 1):

Ohne komplette Überarbeitung der Stack-Exchange-Mechanik ist dies nicht möglich und dies wird vermutlich nicht passieren.

Du kannst aber in Deinem Namen generierte automatische Kommentare nachträglich editieren. Ebenso kannst Du für Dich und andere Interessierte eine Sammlung an Bausteinen auf Meta anlegen. Richtig komfortabel ist dies natürlich alles nicht.

Comment: Zumindiest die Variante _vollständige_ Lokalisierung ist möglich.